# Type mismatch runtime error on ClassTag (Scala)

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I am a C++ programmer and is trying to learn Scala. I want to achieve something similar to the following code using C++ template

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    T* bar;
    /////////////////Other Code Omitted//////////////////////////
};
```

Its counter-part in Scala will not compile due to type erasure

```
class Foo[E](){
    val bar = new E() //Will not compile 
}
```

I have been searching the whole night for a workaround, this seems to be one of them

```
package test
import scala.reflect._

object Type {
  def newInstance[T: ClassTag](init_args: AnyRef*): T = {
    classTag[T].runtimeClass.getConstructors.head.newInstance(init_args: _*).asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}

class Foo[T1:ClassTag](init_args: AnyRef*){
  val bar = Type.newInstance[T1](init_args)
}

class TestClass(val arg:String){
  val data = arg
}
```

However, when I try to instantiate one (`val test = new Foo[Test]("test")`) in the scala console, it gives the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at ParActor.Type$.newInstance(ParActor.scala:32)
  at ParActor.Foo.<init>(ParActor.scala:37)
  ... 35 elided
```

I am not exactly sure what causes the problem and how to fix this. Other work around is also welcomed.

Comment: Not sure, but does `Type.newInstance[T1](init_args: _*)` make a difference?

Comment: @Jasper-M Will try now.

Comment: @Jasper-M Works as a charm! Can you probably help me to explain what is the difference (what is the :_*) exactly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll make it into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should turn

```
Type.newInstance[T1](init_args)
```

into

```
Type.newInstance[T1](init_args: _*)
```

What `: _*` does is turn a list or sequence into a varargs argument. A varargs parameter `AnyRef*` is actually an `IndexedSeq[AnyRef]`, more specifically a `WrappedArray[AnyRef]`. So when you pass `init_args` as an argument to `newInstance` without telling the compiler to interpret it as a varargs argument you are actually passing in `WrappedArray(WrappedArray("test"))`.